# Advice for creating Google Maps-like interface

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to make some web-based board games, and I want the interface to be pannable and zoomable.  Much like how in Google Maps, you can pan and zoom the map, I want the game board to be moved and zoomed.  Unlike Google Maps of course, I do *not* want to work with image tiles.

Can anyone give me recommendations as to what technology to use?  Would this be a good fit for plain HTML? HTML 5 Canvas? or SVG?  Any particular JS libraries to recommend or something else entirely?

I'd like to avoid flash and Java.  And browser compatibility is plus, but not the most important factor.  For example, I think it would probably be OK to require Chrome Frame for older IEs.

Any ideas/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I know you mentioned you didn't want to use images (though I'm not sure how you can build a custom map UI without images?) but Google's map API allows users to use custom maps.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes

Comment: He only said he didn't want "image tiles".  A big SVG which was scrolled/cropped wouldn't use image tiles, nor would a pure canvas solution that simply redrew the visible portion.  Image tiles are a convenient (and compatible!) way to deal with a set of mostly-fixed bitmaps in a browser, but they're not the only way to scroll around a large area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Use the [OpenLayers UI](http://www.openlayers.org/) with a "[fixed](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed-js.html)" strategy to load vector graphics for your board all at once.  (This is overly heavy-weight, probably, but comes with pan-zoom and IE compatibility.)
- Use [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to build your board in SVG, using [RaphaelZPD](https://github.com/somnidea/raphael-zpd) for pan-zoom.  RaphaelZPD isn't cross-browser (even though Raphael is), so you'd need Chrome Frame for IE compatibility.  This would be pretty lightweight, I think.
- Use pure SVG for your board, use [SVGpan](http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/) for pan-zoom.  Chrome Frame required here too, though you could use SVGweb if you wanted.  You could draw your boards right in Inkscape, clean up the SVG's and add whatever ID's you need in the XML (SVG is XML under the hood), and interact with the board with jQuerySVG if you like, or script interaction by hand.  Did I mention that CSS works with SVG?  **I think this is your best bet.**
- I can't think of an advantage to using Canvas here, unless you had *lots* of animation or bitmaps.  SVG is far more transparent in how it works - it's XML under the hood, and when rendered in a page, becomes DOM nodes you can easily manipulate in modern browsers.
- Plain HTML would probably be hard to handle scaling with.  I've seen plenty of image scalers, but haven't seen complex HTML structures, and complexity would be compounded by needing to pan at a zoomed level.

Comment: SVGPan's browser sniffing prevents mousewheel events from zooming in Opera, not good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want total control of your development environment you could create your own web rendering plataform. I think you can use HTML canvas 5 as your interface with the browser.

You can easily implement drag, pan and zoom using HTML canvas. This approach is very similar with game development in many plataforms. [Here](http://www.zoompy.net) an example of using HTML canvas 5 for an interface that supports pan, drag, and zoom.

Having the control of your environment you will have a wide range of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind tiles, I'd suggest checking out [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/) "A JavaScript library for image- and vector-tiled maps using SVG". It's probably possible to borrow some parts from there for panning and zooming.

Comment: I think I do want to avoid tiled because I'm working with a relatively small surface, unlike what surface area that a map itself has to cover. This might be helpful anyway, so I will take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: Polymaps is so complicated, and it doesn't even worth it for this case